# How to use icon on quick_actions

Tags: flutter

I have a doubt about the icon property of Quick Icons.

Can someone give a proper example of how to use it?

A list of names of native supported icons would be great.

There is a way to use custom icons? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the `icon` argument in the [quick_actions](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/quick_actions) package? If so it says it in the doc: `The optional icon should be the name of the native resource (xcassets on iOS or drawable on Android) that the app will display for the quick action.` So if you add `my_icon.xml` to your drawable folder, you can pass `'my_icon'`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I am talking about quick actions. I understood wrong the package usage, I must add a xml icon to the drawable folder of my app, not just specify one inside of the apk drawable folder. Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate @MarcusM. even i'm facing the same issue..like..icons are being shown in the debug mode but not in the release mode..i added the images to the drawable folder..but still the issue happens..and again, it is working fine in debug mode..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same confusion but reading the documentation helped.

**[image: The optional icon should be the name of the native resource (xcassets on iOS or drawable on Android) that the app will display for the quick action.]**

**You can add native android icons following these steps**

1. In Project Hierarchy

   `Your app name > android > new > Image Asset`

   You'll be shown this window.

   [image]

Configure the settings as shown in the image, and change the `icon`, `name` and `color` according to your requirement.

1. After adding the icon, assign its name to the `quick_actions` item

   ```
    ShortcutItem(
             type: 'add',
             localizedTitle: 'Add Goal',
             icon: 'add_icon')
   ```

Comment: after pressing new my Image asset option is disabled in the menu, what to do now?

Comment: Try this tool
https://icon.kitchen/i/H4sIAAAAAAAAA6tWKkvMKU0tVrKqVkpJLMoOyUjNTVWySkvMKU6t1VHKzU8pzQHJRisl5qUU5WemKOkoZeYXA8ny1CSl2FoApT8%2BHkAAAAA%3D

Answer (score 2):

## In addition to the answers regarding Android, here's what you need to do for iOS

1. Generate & download the icons using the [App Icon Generator](https://www.appicon.co/)
2. Open your project in Xcode
3. In the sidebar, "Show the Project Navigator" (icon on the left) and click on "Assets"
   [image: picture for step 3]
4. Click on "+" > "Image Set"
   [image: picture for step 4]
5. You can now enter a name for the image set. When you also want to use the icon on Android, you should name it the same (probably something like "ic_quick_actions_my_action_here") - **The image name must be the same for Android and iOS**.
6. You can now add three versions of your image. Remember that your images are located under `Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` in your extracted app icons. I'm not sure on this, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but here's what I did:

- 1x: Load image "29.png"
- 2x: Load image "60.png"
- 3x: Load image "120.png"
  [image: picture for step 6]

7. Now you should be ready to go! You may need to uninstall the App and reinstall it using Flutter or XCode to see your icon in the quick actions menu.

### Tips

I'm not sure if this is required, but I painted my pictures completely black, which seems to be working flawlessly.

To use Material Icons, you can find & download from a huge list of icons from https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/. I recommend you always to download the SVG version.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on github [topex-psy](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51455#issuecomment-593152837)

You can add icons following these steps :

1. Generate App Icon from here [App Icon Generator](https://appicon.co/) and give it a name like "ic_myicon"
2. You will get 5 folders, paste it in   **\android\app\src\main\res**
3. In the first folder mipmap-hdpi copy your icon and paste in **\android\app\src\main\res\drawable**
4. In same folder **\android\app\src\main\res\drawable** Create new file **quick_actions.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_myicon" /> <!-- here your icon name-->

   </layer-list>
   ```
5. In **\android\app\src\main\res\values** Create new file **styles.xml**

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    ...
     <style name="QuickActions">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/quick_actions</item>
     </style>
    </resources>
   ```

Answer (score -2):

1. To get list of supported icons you should check this out. [supported icons](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)
2. Making use of an icon is simple and straight forward when using material icons provided out of the box.

```dart
 Widget myIcon() {
   return FlatButton(
     child: Icon(
       Icons.add,
       color: Colors.red[300],
     ),
     onPressed: () {
       /** do some cool stuff */
     },
   );
 }
```

3. This is an example of creating a custom icon. you can read more [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html)

```dart
Widget customIcon() {
    final menu = IconData(0xe900, fontFamily: 'customAnimation');
    return Icon(
      menu,
      size: 50.0,
    );
  }
```